# TypeError: must be real number, not str on complex numbers

Tags: python, type-conversion, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to convert my string type data into complex type data.
my data is an excel file which you can check [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DlpN-Z9C9YUceJQ5KAsK3weqa4Od6fJO/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116674736470229441795&rtpof=true&sd=true) (under the name of compressed1.xls )

I got my data from my Matlab code which use the mathematician's *i* and I'm aware Python use engineering convention of *j* for the imaginary unit and I've changed all *i* into *j*. I read my data using Pandas and already convert it into Numpy array.

here is my code so far:

```
compressed = pd.read_excel ('compressed1.xls')
comp_ar = np.array(compressed)
comp_array = comp_ar.astype(np.complex)
```

it arise TypeError on the last line:

> must be real number, not str

I tried using other [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XXaN4ES_y8tibKvEmM_bj1D51lxG9nVd/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116674736470229441795&rtpof=true&sd=true) (BT4864.xlsx) it works well. What should I do? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `complex` to convert strings to complex values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
# Some toy data instead of reading lots from Excel.
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=["4+2j", "2-3j"],
                       b=["3", "2j"]))
df
#       a   b
# 0  4+2j   3
# 1  2-3j  2j

df2 = df.applymap(complex)
df2

#                     a                   b
# 0  4.000000+2.000000j  3.000000+0.000000j
# 1  2.000000-3.000000j  0.000000+2.000000j

# Convert to NumPy.
comp_ar = np.array(df2)
# array([[4.+2.j, 3.+0.j],
#        [2.-3.j, 0.+2.j]])
```

Comment: Hi! I'm afraid I need it to be in Numpy and I tried it it made an error (AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'applymap') . So based on my code, is there something I missed?

Comment: To make it `numpy` you just give the dataframe to `np.array` - I've edited my answer to show this explicitly.  The error you get with `applymap` sounds like you are doing `pd.applymap`, which is incorrect.  `applymap` is a method for DataFrames, which is why I did `df.applymap` in my answer.  Do you see the difference?  Otherwise, if you show the code you tried that makes an error then maybe we can fix it.